# How to combine plotly legends?

Tags: python, plotly

How to edit plotly legends so that "color" and "symbol" will be combined to one?

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


pca = PCA()

X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)

fig = px.scatter(X_pca, x=0, y=1, color=df["subtype"], width=600, height=600, color_discrete_sequence=["red", "orange", "brown", "green"], title="Kernel PCA - tumor subtype vs normal", symbol=df["subtype"], symbol_sequence=['circle', 'circle', 'circle', 'square'])
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=5, line=dict(width=0.5, color='DarkSlateGrey')), selector=dict(mode='markers'))
fig.update_xaxes(automargin=True)
fig.update_yaxes(automargin=True)
fig.update_layout({'plot_bgcolor': 'rgb(240,240,240)', 'paper_bgcolor': 'rgb(240,240,240)',})
fig.show()
fig.write_image("meth_subtype_pca.png")
```

**Current output :**

The legend has `"color, symbol"..."kirp, kirp"` etc. I want to replace this with `"subtype"..."KIRP"`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This event is new to me; it is caused by specifying symbols using a PCA scatterplot. I confirmed the same event by adding symbols in the example in the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/pca-visualization/#2d-pca-scatter-plot). There doesn't seem to be a way to control this so I customize the graph created, one is taking the duplicate legend names and set() them to a single value. Also, the legend title is specified manually.

```
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

df = px.data.iris()
X = df[['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']]

pca = PCA()

X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)

fig = px.scatter(X_pca, 
                 x=0,
                 y=1,
                 color=df["species"],
                 width=600,
                 height=600,
                 color_discrete_sequence=["red", "orange", "brown", "green"],
                 title="Kernel PCA - tumor subtype vs normal",
                 symbol=df["species"],
                 symbol_sequence=['circle', 'circle', 'square']
                )
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=5, line=dict(width=0.5, color='DarkSlateGrey')), selector=dict(mode='markers'))
fig.update_xaxes(automargin=True)
fig.update_yaxes(automargin=True)
fig.update_layout({'plot_bgcolor': 'rgb(240,240,240)', 'paper_bgcolor': 'rgb(240,240,240)',})

# update
for data in fig.data:
    data['name'] = list(set(data['name'].split(', ')))[0]
fig.layout['legend']['title']['text'] = 'color'

fig.show()
#fig.write_image("meth_subtype_pca.png")
```

[image]